# redirect only www requests to https in nginx configuration file

Tags: nginx

I have a node application running on EBS where I want to enforce https. I have overridden the nginx configuration file with the following command

`server_name    www.mydomain.com;
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$REQUEST_URI permanent;
}`

This works fine but I have a separate dev domain of dev.mydomain.com which I want to connect to over http rather than https.

Is there an nginx prefix variable  can access to do something like...

`server_name    www.mydomain.com;
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https" && $uri_prefix == 'www') {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$REQUEST_URI permanent;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Nginx doesn't allow multiple or nested if statements

You could try this configuration but...it's not so elegant
`

```
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
   set $myvar http;

}
if ($host ~ ^www) {
   set $myvar "${myvar}www";
}

if ($myvar = 'httpwww') {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$server_name$REQUEST_URI permanent;
}
```

`